# Downloading correct vim packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

I need help reconfiguring my vim!! In the process of working with it, I decided to download the .vim files and reinstall. After reinstalling I have had some major problems with my vimruntime. My vim files are located at /usr/asf/vim. I can't figure out where to get the original syntax files that come with a fresh install of ubuntu. Currently Vim is outputting the error

```
"E484: Can't open file /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim"
```

I no longer have a .vim file. I have tried a ton of things. I became so frustrated in fact that I did a sudo apt-get install vim-* do load all relative packages. I have visited http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package_metas and have gone to the software center. I still can't get

```
 :syntax on
```

to work. I would really appreciate help on this.

Comment: `/usr/asf`?  What madness is this?  Anyhow, if you want to reinstall `vim`, try `sudo apt-get purge vim; sudo apt-get install vim`

Comment: I tried that. It still isn't giving me the syntax files.

Comment: After a fresh install, you should be able to execute `vim -N -u NONE -i NONE -c 'syntax on'` and have syntax highlighting when you then edit some file. You should also be able to execute `:scriptnames` and see a list of the loaded runtime files, probably starting with `1: /usr/share/vim/vim74/syntax/syntax.vim`.

Comment: Something else you might try: `/usr/bin/dpkg --get-selections | grep vim` to see which vim packages you have installed. The list on my Ubuntu system includes `vim-common` and `vim-runtime`. I thought those were automatically installed with `vim`, but maybe you have to install those separately.

Comment: @garyjohn, it didn't work but I think I know now it is a problem with the runtime environment. I think I had some conflicts somewhere in the system and so the runtime enviorment was beings stored in another location. Here's the funny thing though, when I ran locate syntax.vim I can't find the syntax file although I found all the other scripts located in /usr/share/vim/addons/

Comment: Similarly, I don't have /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc/help.txt however I do have in /usr/share/vim/vim74/doc$ help.dex intro.dex usr_01.dex usr_02.dex...etc. etc. So I have all the help files but it can't read it.

Comment: I would not expect syntax.vim to be among the addon files; it's one of Vim's normal configuration files and I would expect it to be in $VIMRUNTIME/syntax. Very strange. I have no idea why your help files would have a .dex suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install a proper Vim on ubuntu, run this command in your terminal:

```
$ sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

This should get you a working Vim (both CLI and GUI).

Your user directory is:

```
/home/username/
```

often shortened to:

```
~
```

That's where you are supposed to put *your* configuration:

```
~/.vim/  <= the directory where you put colorschemes and plugins
~/.vimrc <= the file where you put your settings/mappings
```

These directory and file are *not* created by Vim: you must create them yourself.

```
$ cd
$ mkdir .vim
$ touch .vimrc
```

***NEVER*** do *anything* in `/usr/share/vim`. ***NEVER.***